# Get Element's width by not appending it to Dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I'm trying to get an element's width by using the jQuery's .width() function. I'm trying to get the width of the element by appending that element into the Dom.

```
$('body').append("<span id='longText'></span>");
var longElement = $('body').find("#longText");
longElement.text(longestMeasure);
var longeElementWidth = longElement.width();
```

This method is working fine. But can we get the width of the element by not injecting it to the Dom?

Comment: It's not possible. For the width to be calculated the element needs to be part of the DOM for the renderer to calculate the value based on the element's relation to all others in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You **CAN'T** get it done without inserting it to the DOM but here is a trick I can think of and it's that insert it into dom as hidden, get whatever CSS property you wish and remove the element afterwards.

Only diff to your code is I set display to none and remove element right after I obtained width.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').css('display','none').append("<span id='longText'></span>");
    var longElement = $('body').find("#longText");
    longElement.text(longestMeasure);
    var longeElementWidth = longElement.width();
    longElement(remove);
}
```

Oh and I also wrapped everything up to be executed when document is ready.